# Why is test.elem undefined in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title gives the error I get when I use the following:

```
var test = {

    elem : undefined,

    init : function() { console.log("test.init() fired");

        elem = $("#id"); 
        console.log("elem assigned to jQuery object");

        elem.click(function() { console.log("elem clicked"); });
        console.log("elem click handler created");

    }

};

test.init();
test.elem.click();
```

I don't understand.  If I run `test.init()` where it assigns the value for `test.elem`, why would it be undefined when I try to access it later?

Comment: I'm such an idiot.  That's when you know after 10 hours, it's probably time to leave work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new reference called 'elem' inside of the init function rather than referencing test.elem.

Inside init you need to assign the element to 'this.elem', so it would read:

```
init : function() {
    console.log("test.init() fired");

    this.elem = $("#id"); 

    console.log("elem assigned to jQuery object");

    this.elem.click(function() {
        console.log("elem clicked");
    });

    console.log("elem click handler created");
}
```

Comment: Yea I totally goofed.  I had it correct everywhere else, but forgot this one spot.  I've been working too long. Thanks for the second pair of eyes!